# Apple Pencil and iPad but no Wi-Fi

Tags: ipad, internet, cellular-data, apple-pencil

My iPad is not on a data plan and I don’t have Wi-Fi access in my classroom.

Will I still be able to use my Apple Pencil?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, because the first, second and third generation Apple Pencils all use BlueTooth to connect to the iPad, and not Wi-Fi.